# Why is this program not necessarily an MCMC?

Tags: self-study

In Chapter 1, [Handbook of Markov Chain Monte Carlo](https://amzn.to/44WojDz), Geyer writes

> Suppose you have a computer program
>
> ```
> Initialize x   
> repeat { 
>       Generate pseudorandom change to x 
>       Output x  
> }
> ```
>
> If x is the entire state of the computer program exclusive of random
> number generator seeds (which we ignore, pretending pseudorandom is
> random), this is MCMC. It is important that x must be the entire state
> of the program. Otherwise the resulting stochastic process need not be
> Markov.

Why is this program not necessarily an MCMC if x is not the entire state of the program?

Comment: This comment is rather obscure and unnecessary. In particular, it ignores the central purpose of MCMC algorithms that is to generate a Markov chain with a *given* stationary distribution. There is no trace of the input stationary distribution in the pseudo-code.

Comment: MCMC, by definition, depends on immediately previous state, and some generic transition rule with a random step. Any additional memory of previous states, or initialization states, makes it not Markov Chain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain